# how to delete the border from a WPF treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

[image]

I want to show that when I selected treeViewItem, treeViewItem changes background. I delete TreeView border. But left TreeView background. How do I remove the space blue color in the image that is red circled?

My XAML code is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LibraryTreeViewItemStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="tv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187"  Background="#FF213757"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LibraryTreeViewItemStyle}" BorderBrush="#FF1B1919" >
```

Answer (score 7):

I just used `BorderThickness="0"` within my `<TreeView *STUFF* ></TreeView>` call in XAML.

(My Xaml code as reference)

```
    <TreeView x:Name="tvReports" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="Hidden"  Background="AliceBlue"></TreeView>
```

Answer (score 4):

this Solved my problem Scrollviewer inside treeview has a border thickness

```xml
<Style TargetType="TreeView">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                    <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ScrollViewer Background="Transparent" Focusable="False"
                                      CanContentScroll="False"
                                      BorderThickness="0">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

change TreeView Padding to `0` (default value is `1`):

```
<TreeView Padding="0" ...
```

Comment: i tried Padding = "0" BorderThickness="0". but result same.

Comment: @gyungjune, nice to hear that. if Padding was not a solution, please post your own solution as another answer

Comment: @nikotromus try setting BorderThickness=0

Answer (score 0):

Because the border belongs to the ScrollViewer, simply overlap it setting `Margin="-1"`.